# Mock method from external file called by a React component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I have a React component which is calling methods defined in another file, something like this:

```
import { realMethod } from '../some-library';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const result = realMethod();
  const field = result.someField;
  /* Rest of the code... */  
}
```

I want to write a test for `MyComponent` using react-testing-library and it's breaking because when it comes to the line `const field = result.someField` it doesn't know what it is (`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'someField'`).

So far I wrote this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render, screen, userEvent, within } from '../../test-utils';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import * as realMethods from '../some-library';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('should do stuff', () => {
    const spyMethod = jest.spyOn(
      realMethods,
      'realMethod',
    );
    render(
      <MyComponent />,
    );
    /* ... */
  });
});
```

How can I mock `realMethod` and make it return something useful?

Answer (score 0):

The spyOn itself shouldn't break your code. It looks like your `realMethod` does not return an object that contain `someField`, e.g.:

```js
export const realMethod = () => ({ someField: 42 })
```

You can mock it like this:

```js
jest.spyOn(realMethods, 'realMethod').mockReturnValue({ someField: 'mocked' });
```